# Origen de las distintas acepciones de "presente"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado

Volviendo a ver hoy *Kung Fu Panda*, me he acordado de una frase de esa película que me encanta:

> El ayer ya es historia, y el mañana es un misterio. En cambio el hoy es un regalo, por eso se le llama presente.

Efectivamente, si buscamos la palabra en el diccionario, aparecen las dos acepciones que conocemos:

> **[presente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U685C9x)**
>
> Del lat. *praesens, -entis*.
>
> 2. adj. Dicho del tiempo: Que es aquel en que está quien habla. U. t. c. s. m.
> 3. m. Obsequio, regalo que alguien da a otra persona en señal de reconocimiento o de afecto.

La pregunta que me hago es qué hay de cierto en tan poética frase. ¿Es casualidad que la palabra "presente" tenga ambas acepciones? ¿O hay algún vínculo entre ambas que se me escapa? Lo curioso es que frase es posible porque en el idioma original de la película, la palabra "[present](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/present)" también tiene ambas acepciones:

> - not past or future : existing or happening now
> - to give something to someone in a formal way or in a ceremony

Me resulta raro que la coincidencia se mantenga en ambos idiomas. Así pues, ¿cuál es la conexión?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Presente* es el participio activo de *presentar*; el significado original de *presentar* es *hacer ser* o *hacer visible*.

De este significado original, la acepción de *regalo* viene porque un regalo se hace visible (se presenta) delante del regalado. Y la acepción de tiempo actual, seguramente es un epíteto que reemplaza a *día presente* o *tiempo presente*.

En inglés, al igual que en español, existe esa misma coincidencia, probablemente, porque ambos recibieron la acepción de *regalo* del francés (la de tiempo presente ya existía en latín). Nótese que forma más habitual de referirse a este concepto en español es *regalo*, y en inglés es *gift* (*present/presente* es algo más formal).

Comment: Luego el día presente es el día que se ha _hecho visible_ ante nosotros, igual que un regalo se _hace visible_ frente al regalado. ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: No hay de qué! Y lo mismo con el resto de acepciones de la palabra: _te presento a Fulanito_, _me presento a las elecciones_, _Menganito presenta un programa de TV_, (pasando lista en clase) _¿Jamito? ¡Presente!_...

Comment: Correcto, y la etimología (también en inglés) es antigua: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=present

Comment: @leonbloy me ha encantado la etimología: "prae-" + "esse" (estar antes).